# Jmeter generating reports for each thread(user) in case of multiple users logged

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have created a thread group with user credentials passed from csv file . Using CSV Data Set Config, i have passed 10 different credentials to the test plan and executed it.

I have used different listeners, but not able to generate the report for each user. The report is generated for the requests and responses for the entire threads and not any individual threads.

If anyone got to know about generating the report for the requests and responses for individual threads, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) as prefix/postfix for the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label, this way you will be able to distinguish the results for different virtual users, to wit instead of `HTTP Request` use `HTTP Request - User: ${__threadNum}`

   [image]
2. Similarly you can add a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to add credential from the CSV file to the sampler label, this way you will get a human-readable names instead of virtual user IDs

   [image: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html]